# How to begin an Oracle transaction in Navicat

Tags: oracle11g, navicat

I'm trying to have a transaction for simple queries written in Navicat Premium, when using a Oracle database:

```
ALTER TABLE "APPLICATIONS_EXTENSION"
ADD CONSTRAINT "APPLICATIONS_EXTENSION_F01" FOREIGN KEY ("APPLICATION_ID")
                     REFERENCES "MYDB"."APPLICATIONS" ("APPLICATION_ID")
    DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED;

UPDATE "APPLICATIONS_EXTENSION" SET "APPLICATION_ID" = 100000; -- Fake ID

UPDATE "APPLICATIONS_EXTENSION" SET "APPLICATION_ID" = 1; -- Good ID

COMMIT;
```

This should execute fine, since, at `COMMIT` time, the *deferred* foreign-key constraint is satisfied.

However, Navicat seems to have auto-commit active, so, right-after the second statement an error is thrown:

```
> ORA-02091: transaction rolled back
ORA-02291: integrity constraint (MYDB.APPLICATIONS_EXTENSION_F01) violated - parent key not found
```

I found no way to have auto-commit off, nor an explicit way to start a transaction.

The "Automatically start a transaction" option in the "Records" tab of Navicat Options seems to just apply to table views (as its tab name seemed to indicate).

Comment: You can't explicitly start a transaction, and I'm not sure it would help. What happens if you just do `set autocommit off` before your first update? (I don't have Navicat, but that works in SQL\*Plus etc.)

Comment: Already tried: `set autocommit off` `> ORA-00922: missing or invalid option`